# ValueError: could not convert string to float: when using input function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I read similar threads with my error and could not find the solution. In most other threads it seemed that people were inputting data incorrectly, but as you can see I am inputting the values with the correct typology. I can't seem to find what else I could be missing. Any ideas?

```
def main():
    a, b, c, d, e, f  = float(input("Enter a, b, c, d, e, f: "))



    x = ((e * d) - (b * f))/ (
        (a * d) - (b * c) )

    y = ((a * f) - (e * c)) / (
        (a * d) - (b * c) )

    print("x is %f and y is %f" % (x,y))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Error message:

```
>>>Enter a, b, c, d, e, f: 9.0, 4.0, 3.0, -5.0, -6.0, -21.0
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '9.0, 4.0, 3.0, -5.0, -6.0, -21.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

the `float()` function tries to convert the entire string to a single float. Technically this would work:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f  = [float(number) for number in input("Enter a, b, c, d, e, f: ").split(', ')]
```

But keep in mind there's no error handling if it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

If you ensure the decimal point is always included

```
from ast import literal_eval
a, b, c, d, e, f = literal_eval(input("Enter a, b, c, d, e, f: "))
```

If the decimal point is missing, the corresponding variable will be an int instead of a float

Comment: I was taught it is bad coding practice to use eval() function for such a task. Is literal_eval different?

Comment: @user3268003, yes, completely different. literal_eval only works for valid literals. eval can erase your harddrive and other evil things

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a series of float values, separated by commas, cannot be converted to a single `float`.

Either ask for each float individually, or split up the input string on commas and loop through them converting.

I recommend asking for each float individually.  Write a function `input_float()` that takes input from the user, attempts to convert to float, and tells the user if there was a problem; it can have a loop that keeps looping until the user successfully enters a float value.

You might want to make your `input_float()` function accept a string to display as a prompt, another string to show on error, and a function to validate the input.  So if the user must enter a float value between 0 and 100, you could make a validation function that performed this check.

Once you have written a flexible `input_float()` function, you can use it over and over again in your program.